# finding minimal polynomial for $\frac{\theta^5}{5}$ when minimal polynomial for $\theta$ is $x^3-2$

Tags: minimal-polynomials

suppose  $f(x)= x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial for $\theta$. How can I find a minimal polynomial for $a =  \frac{\theta^5}{5}$

My idea was to substitute $u = \sqrt[5]{5 \cdot x} $

and then plug it into $f(x)$ and reduce it to a minimal polynomial.

While $f(u)$ would have $a$ as a root, it may not be in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

So my question is, is there any method to find a polynomial or even better a minimal polynomial?

Comment: A "better" minimal polynomial? There is only one up to a multiple by a degree zero polynomial (=a number different from zero)

Comment: If $\theta^3=2$ then $\theta^5=2\theta^2$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is a punctuation error. I meant  ..a polynomial, or even better, a minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have that

$$\;\theta\in\left\{\,\sqrt[3]2,\,\sqrt[3]2\,\omega\,,\,\,\sqrt[3]2\,\omega^2\,\right\}\;,\;\;\omega:=e^{2\pi i/3}\implies\frac{\theta^5}5\in\left\{\,\frac{2^{5/3}}5\,,\,\,\frac{2^{5/3}\omega^2}5\,,\,\,\frac{2^{5/3}\omega}5\,\right\}$$

and now:

$$r=\frac{\theta^5}5\implies125r^3=2^5=32\implies g(x):=x^3-\frac{32}{125}\in\Bbb Q[x]$$

makes the cut.

Comment: but it looks like I can use this method only, if I can separate $\theta$. what if $\theta$ is a root of $x^3-x-2$?

Comment: @user315567 Then things get way tougher...